# Get-AzureStorageFile doesn't set LastModified property

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage-files

When trying to get files out of an Azure share file directory I'm using powershell code like below (similar to the example from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestoragefile?view=azurermps-4.4.1#examples))

```
$file = Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $fileShare -Path "tolearn\doc" | Get-AzureStorageFile | Where-Object {$_.GetType().Name -eq "CloudFile"}
```

For example, lets assume we have one child folder and two files under the 'doc' folder.
The code from above will return these two files, which is expected.

However*LastModified* property remains 'null' like it is shown on the picture (as well as other properties)

[image]

I need *LastModified* property in order to filter files that are older than certain date in order to delete them. But, since this value is null, this is not possible.
Any idea on how to do this is very much appreciated.
Code to do that should look like this:

```
$file = Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $fileShare -Path "tolearn\doc" | Get-AzureStorageFile | Where-Object { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CloudFile" -and $currentTime -gt $_.Properties.LastModified.AddMinutes($offset)}
```

Please note, if I query for one file like this, for example

```
$file = Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $fileShare -Path "tolearn\doc\Word2003.doc"
```

*LastModified* property would be properly set.
So, it looks like that piped call to the **Get-AzureStorageFile** method doesn't set these properties to files or directories returned.

Is my approach bad here, is there a better way to filter files in order to delete them from Azure file share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, it looks like that piped call to the Get-AzureStorageFile method
>   doesn't set these properties to files or directories returned.

I get the same result as you, can't get `LastModified` vaule.

As a workaround, we can use `foreach`to get every file's `Properties.LastModified`, like this:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> $file = Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $share -Path "jason"
PS C:\Users\jason> $c = $file | Get-AzureStorageFile
PS C:\Users\jason> $list = $c.name
PS C:\Users\jason> $list
04.PNG
08.PNG
test3
test4
PS C:\Users\jason> foreach($a in $list){$path = 'jason/'+$a ; $b = Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName jasonshare1 -Path $path -Context $ctx; $b.Properties.LastModified }


DateTime      : 11/22/2017 2:31:13 AM
UtcDateTime   : 11/22/2017 2:31:13 AM
LocalDateTime : 11/22/2017 10:31:13 AM
Date          : 11/22/2017 12:00:00 AM
Day           : 22
DayOfWeek     : Wednesday
DayOfYear     : 326
Hour          : 2
Millisecond   : 0
Minute        : 31
Month         : 11
Offset        : 00:00:00
Second        : 13
Ticks         : 636469146730000000
UtcTicks      : 636469146730000000
TimeOfDay     : 02:31:13
Year          : 2017

DateTime      : 11/22/2017 2:31:14 AM
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason Ye - MSFT for looking into this and providing detailed code example. Workaround will do the trick now that I know for sure you have the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To set the properties of a File you need to call:

```
$file.FetchAttributes()
```

Here's a short example:

```
$files = Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Context $ctx | where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "CloudFile"}
foreach($file in $files) {
    $file.FetchAttributes();
    if ($file.Properties.LastModified -ge $fromDate) {
        # Download file
        Get-AzureStorageFileContent -File $file -Destination $downloadDir
    }
}
```

Based on the information provided in:
[Azure CloubdBlob's Properties.Length returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332295/azure-cloubdblobs-properties-length-returns-0)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and giving an answer. I did something similar (involves foreach loop). But the question was related to piping those two commands (as in the example on the docs site), in which case some attributes were not populated. Bottom line, it comes to foreach loop and either retrieving file by file, which will populate all attributes, or use your approach and gather all files, and then attributes as per file. The thing is, it cannot be filtered by date in a piped command call, so additional work and foreach are required.